# How to work with limits when one part shrinks and other grows rapid

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hello I am having confusion on how to approach limits of sequences in cases when say one part of it blows up to infinity, and another goes to zero.

For example

the sequence $$X=(n!)^{\frac{1}{n^2}}$$

I know that n! will approach infinity rapidly, but also that the exponent will approach zero.

I know that the limit is one, but I don't know how to actually show something like this ( without using things like log)

So how can I approach these type of sequences? Thanks

Comment: One makes estimates. For example $n!\le n^n$ is good enough here, at least if we know how $n^{1/n}$ behaves.

Comment: $n\le n!\le n^n$ then the sandwich theorem.

Comment: Why would you not use logarithms?

Comment: In this case, you don't need to.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways
to show that
$(n!)^{1/n}
< cn
$
for some constant $c$.
Once you have that,
then knowing that
$c^{1/n} \to 1$ and
$n^{1/n} \to 1$
as $n \to \infty$
will give you what you want.

Here are two.

By the AGM inequality
$(n!)^{1/n}
=(\prod_{k=1}^n k)^{1/n}
\le \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k}{n}
= \frac{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}{n}
= \frac{n+1}{2}
$

Pairing opposite values
in the definition of $n!$,

$\begin{array}\\
(n!)^2
&=\prod_{k=1}^n k(n+1-k)\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^n (k(n+1)-k^2)\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^n (\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}-\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}+k(n+1)-k^2)\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^n (\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}-(\frac{n+1}{2}-k)^2)\\
&<\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{(n+1)^2}{4}\\
&=\left(\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}\right)^n\\
&=\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^{2n}\\
\text{so}\\
(n!)^{1/n}
&<\frac{n+1}{2}\\
\end{array}
$

Here is a magic proof that
$n^{1/n} \to 1$.
By Bernoulli's inequality,
$(1+n^{-1/2})^n
\ge 1+n(n^{-1/2})
=1+n^{1/2}
> n^{1/2}
$,
so,
raising to the
$2/n$ power,
$n^{1/n}
< (1+n^{-1/2})^2
=1+2n^{-1/2}+n^{-1}
<1+3n^{-1/2}
\to 1
$.

Answer (score 0):

Infine and zero products and powers are the essence of many sequence issues. When factorials appear, [Stirling-like formulas and their bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) can be useful, for instance:

$$\sqrt{2\pi}\ n^{n+1/2}e^{-n} \le n! \le e\ n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}\,.$$

Hence, you get:

$$(\sqrt{2\pi})^{1/n^2}\ n^{1/n+1/2n^2}e^{-1/n} \le (n!)^{\frac{1}{n^2}} \le (e)^{1/n^2}\ n^{1/n+1/2n^2}e^{-1/n}\,.$$

For any $C> 0$, $C^{1/n^2}\to 1$, $n^{1/n}$  and $n^{1/n^2} \to 1$ as $n\to \infty$, so will  $e^{-1/n}$.

[Graphics](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bn!%7D%5E%7B1%2Fn%5E2%7D) finaly convince you that the limit is unity.